# Sonar Scanner Says that File Is Missing for Present File

Tags: sonarqube

> Sonar 5.6
>
> Java Plugin 4.2

When I run the Sonar scanner, the analysis says that `libsetuid-linux-1.0.2.so` is missing. But the file is definitely there. I can exactly see that the file it wants is present on the file system. Here is the proof and the exception:

> ls -ltr
>   /home/dir/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain.setuid/libsetuid-linux/1.0.2/fdd9c0360aea4b4333b4e0b82ff9506a5a73fa5b/libsetuid-linux-1.0.2.so

Gives:

> -rw-r--r--  1 user  group  17735 Sep  6 16:10 /home/dir/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain.setuid/libsetuid-linux/1.0.2/fdd9c0360aea4b4333b4e0b82ff9506a5a73fa5b/libsetuid-linux-1.0.2.so

The exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No files nor directories matching '/home/dir/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty.toolchain.setuid/libsetuid-linux/1.0.2/fdd9c0360aea4b4333b4e0b82ff9506a5a73fa5b/libsetuid-linux-1.0.2.so'
        at org.sonar.java.AbstractJavaClasspath.getFilesFromProperty(AbstractJavaClasspath.java:90)
        at org.sonar.java.JavaClasspath.init(JavaClasspath.java:50)
        at org.sonar.java.AbstractJavaClasspath.getElements(AbstractJavaClasspath.java:258)
        at org.sonar.java.SonarComponents.getJavaClasspath(SonarComponents.java:122)
        at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.<init>(JavaSquid.java:78)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.execute(JavaSquidSensor.java:86)
        at org.sonar.batch.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:57)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:83)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
        at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
        at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:240)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
        at org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask.run(SonarQubeTask.java:84)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:228)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:621)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:604)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is a known issue in the Java Plugin 4.2. It is supposed to be fixed when 4.3 comes out on September 16, 2016:

https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1831